# Почему не запускаются BASH файлы в Win 10?

Tags: bash, path, git-bash

Я пытаюсь запустить любой `.sh` файл в моей win 10, но они не запускаются.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из под консоли git-bash всё работает, но это не выход.
Такое впечатление, что винда просто не может найти `bash`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что в переменной $PATH:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не совсем понимаю, как мне указать винде, где лежит баш. Править первую строку файла `.sh` или шаманить в $PATH?

Спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE**

Использование sh приводит к ошибке: `sh : Имя "sh" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выпо лняемой программы.`
А команда `bash ./deploy.sh` к таким ошибкам:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что bash файлы не нативны для Windows и PowerShell. PowerShell ничего не знает о shebang строке. Пробуйте запускать через `sh deploy.sh` или `bash deploy.sh`

Comment: @insolor, см **UPDATE**

Comment: Пересохраните файл так, чтобы окончания строк были \n (LF), а не \r\n (CRLF), тогда ошибка с \r уйдет. Например, в vscode в панели статуса справа внизу переключатель: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8qa7.png

Comment: @insolor, спасибо! добавление bash в команду, и LF решило проблему, теперь всё работает!